# Hashet maximum size appears to be 961

Tags: java, minecraft, hashset

## Introduction

Hello everyone. I have been encountering a problem for about 2 weeks now and I **cannot** seem to be able to find out why it is happening. *So, what is the case?*

## Rough explanation of my project

I am writing a *Minecraft* tool, which reads all the region files of a save file, and checks them. If they have player-placed blocks, the chunk that block is in is marked as safe, and will later not be deleted; otherwise the chunk is deleted after the enqueuing process is completed, since there are supposed to happen several enqueuings.

## The problem

The program seems to run fine, until it hits 961 elements in the hashset I am using. *That hashset contains strings, that are used to determine if a chunk has been marked as safe.* Once there are 961 elements, it acts like it cannot add any more to it, as if it runs out of memory, although that is not true, I've assigned 2gB of memory to it and still, nothing. I've tested it many times, with many different parameters but it tops at 961.

## The error

While adding elements to the HashSet, it tops up at 961, and does **not** add any more than that. Tested with 2gB of RAM too, but no luck.

## The code

Here is my code. Do not be overwhelmed by it, it is pretty simple.

The `Options` class is just a class that loads some options to work with. Not worth mentioning.

The `Main` class:

```
public class Main {

    Options options = new Options();
    Deleter deleter;

    public Main() {
        deleter = new Deleter(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Load world?");
            System.out.println("(Y for yes/Q for quit): ");
            String s = br.readLine();
            while (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    main.deleter.loadWorld();
                    System.out.println("Enqueue?");
                    System.out.println("(E for enqueue/Q for quit): ");
                    s = br.readLine();
                    while (s.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) { // While user wants to enqueue
                        main.deleter.enqueue();
                        System.out.println("Delete?");
                        System.out.println("(E for enqueue/D for delete/Q for quit)");
                        s = br.readLine();
                    }
                    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                        main.deleter.delete();
                    }

                }
            } // If input == Quit, do this
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Deleter` class

```
public class Deleter {

    private Options options;
    private ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>(1000);
    private HashSet<String> safeChunks = new HashSet<>(20000);
    private ArrayList<Integer> blockIDsList = new ArrayList<>(100);
    private int totalChunksEnqueued = 0;
    private int chunksEnqueued = 0;

    public Deleter(Main main) {
        this.options = main.getOptions();
        totalChunksEnqueued = 0;
    }

    public void loadWorld() {
        String folderName = options.getSaveFolderFile().getParentFile().getName();
        System.out.println("--------Loading world: " + folderName + "--------");
        File filesTemp[] = options.getSaveFolderFile().listFiles();
        for (File file : filesTemp) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith("mca")) {
//              RegionFile regionFile = new RegionFile(file);
                files.add(file);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("--------World loaded successfully--------");
    }

    public void enqueue() {
        System.out.println("--------Enqueuing--------");
        chunksEnqueued = 0;
        try {
            options.reloadConfig();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        int totalFiles = options.getSaveFolderFile().listFiles().length;
        int counter = 0;

        //START

        //Actual enqueuing takes place here
        for (File file : files) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Progress: " + counter + "/" + totalFiles + ". Total chunks enqueued: " + totalChunksEnqueued);
            RegionFile regionFile = new RegionFile(file);
            for (int chunkX = 0; chunkX < 32; chunkX++) {
                for (int chunkZ = 0; chunkZ < 32; chunkZ++) {
                    DataInputStream chunk = regionFile.getChunkDataInputStream(chunkX, chunkZ);
                    if (regionFile.hasChunk(chunkX, chunkZ)) {

                        try {
                            Tag root = Tag.readNamedTag(chunk);

                            CompoundTag level = root.getCompound("Level");
                            ListTag sections = level.getList("Sections");

                            for (int i = 0; i < sections.size(); i++) {
                                CompoundTag section = (CompoundTag) sections.get(i);
                                byte[] blocksArray = section.getByteArray("Blocks");
                                byte[] addsArray = section.getByteArray("Add");
                                byte Y = section.getByte("Y");

                                boolean worked = false;
                                for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
                                    for (int z = 0; z < 16; z++) {
                                        for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
//                                          int realX = regionX * 32 + chunkX * 16 + x;
                                            int realY = Y * 16 + y;
//                                          int realZ = regionZ * 32 + chunkZ * 16 + z;
                                            if (realY >= minY && realY <= maxY) {
                                                // Copied from Chunk Format page.
                                                int BlockPos = (y * 16 * 16) + (z * 16) + (x);
                                                byte BlockID_a = blocksArray[BlockPos];
                                                short BlockID = BlockID_a;
                                                if (addsArray.length != 0) {
                                                    byte BlockID_b = nibble4(addsArray, BlockPos);
                                                    BlockID = (short) (BlockID_a + (BlockID_b << 8));
                                                }
                                                for (int block : blockIDs) {
                                                    if (BlockID == block) {
                                                        worked = true;
                                                        markSafeChunks(regionFile, chunkX, chunkZ, radius);
                                                        break;
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }
                                            if (worked)
                                                break;

                                        }
                                        if (worked)
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    if (worked)
                                        break;
                                }
                                if (worked)
                                    break;
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                regionFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        //END

        System.out.println("Chunks enqueued this time: " + chunksEnqueued);
        System.out.println("Total chunks enqueued: " + totalChunksEnqueued);
        System.out.println("--------Finished enqueueing--------");
    }

    public void delete() {
        System.out.println("--------Deleting--------");
        try {
            options.reloadConfig();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        int totalFiles = options.getSaveFolderFile().listFiles().length;
        //START

        // Deletion takes place here

        for (File file : files) {
            RegionFile regionFile = new RegionFile(file);
            // You are now in a region file.
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Progress: " + counter + "/" + totalFiles);
            for (int chunkX = 0; chunkX < 32; chunkX++) {
                for (int chunkZ = 0; chunkZ < 32; chunkZ++) {
                    if (!safeChunks.contains("" + chunkX + "_" + chunkZ) && regionFile.hasChunk(chunkX, chunkZ)) {
                        try {
                            regionFile.deleteChunk(chunkX, chunkZ);
                            chunksDeleted++;
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            return;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                regionFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //END

        System.out.println("Chunks deleted: " + chunksDeleted);
        System.out.println("--------Finished enqueueing--------");

    }

    private synchronized void markSafeChunks(RegionFile regionFile, int chunkX, int chunkZ, int radius) {
        if (radius == 0)
            safeChunks.add("" + chunkX + "_" + chunkZ);
        else
            for (int surX = chunkX - radius; surX <= chunkX + radius; surX++) {
                for (int surZ = chunkZ - radius; surZ <= chunkZ + radius; surZ++) {
                    boolean b = surX > chunkX / 32 && surX < chunkX / 32 + 32;
                    b &= surZ > chunkZ / 32 && surZ < chunkZ / 32 + 32;
                    if (b && regionFile.hasChunk(surX, surZ) && !safeChunks.contains("" + surX + "_" + surZ)) {
                        safeChunks.add("" + surX + "_" + surZ);
                        chunksEnqueued++;
                        totalChunksEnqueued++;
                    }

                }
            }
    }
```

---

Any ideas why this 961-ceiling problem is happening?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's no reference to a HashSet in your code. Also check if HashSet already contains the values you're trying to add after 961 elements.

Comment: @11thdimension There **is** indeed a reference to a HashSet in the Deleter class, and I **do** check if that HashSet contains the values, before adding them..

Comment: I meant that you're probably adding the existing keys repetitively, that's why size of set doesn't change. Your code generates `32x32 = 1024` keys, which is very close to 961.

Comment: @11thdimension Ok, as it seems, I had **indeed** been adding the same keys over and over again. The keys have same X,Z coordinates in each region file, but each region file is different, and that was my mistake. I _skipped_ specifying in which region file each X,Z coordinate exists. **Thanks a lot for helping me out!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capacity of a HashSet is always a power of 2 and you can add more than 1 billion elements to it.  However, it does ignore duplicates, so if you keep adding elements, but those elements are already in the set it won't increase in size.

If you didn't get an `OutOfMemoryError` it didn't run out of memory.

BTW The simple way to break out of multiple loops is to use a label e.g.

```
outer:
while (something)
   while (nested)
      while (moreNested) {
         //
         if (condition)
             break outer;
      }
```

This means you don't need your `working` variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code suggestion; I am already using it! As it seems, I had **indeed** been adding the same keys repetitively, by mistake. ***Thanks a lot for helping me clear it out!***